# UINavigationController inside UITabBarController - Two Navigation Bars?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Here are the steps I've followed - pretty much this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFNtD098Bbk&feature=player_embedded

- Create new Tab Bar Application
- Looking at MainWindow.xib I drag a UIViewController in
- Drag one of the tabs View Controllers onto the UIViewController
- Set up buttons and actions top push the new view
- Note I have no idea how he did the last step in the video, dragging one tab object onto another won't work for me

The navigation works fine, the new view gets pushed and all that jazz.  But when I go to the tab that has the navigation controller it has two navigationBar's.

I can't find where to get rid of this for the life of me.  It must be something really simple but I've been searching for way too long.

None of the many tutorials I've found have this problem, not does the project files of those tutorials even though my project looks pretty much the same as theirs in IB.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the useless navigation bar?

I'm using Xcode version 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I missed it but the answer was stupidly simple.

Just needed to delete the UIToolbar from the nib file, can't believe I didn't find that earlier.